# how to can read browsers cookie?

Tags: c#

i want to read browser(`for all domains`) cookie(`for example firefox`)if is it possible? i saw this code in msdn but dont returned all cookies!! and can't conect to all domains!

```
 static void Main(string[] argss)

{

    string args = "your domain";
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(args);
    request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();



    // Print the properties of each cookie.
    foreach (Cookie cook in response.Cookies)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cookie:");
        Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", cook.Name, cook.Value);
        Console.WriteLine("Domain: {0}", cook.Domain);
        Console.WriteLine("Path: {0}", cook.Path);
        Console.WriteLine("Port: {0}", cook.Port);
        Console.WriteLine("Secure: {0}", cook.Secure);

        Console.WriteLine("When issued: {0}", cook.TimeStamp);
        Console.WriteLine("Expires: {0} (expired? {1})",
            cook.Expires, cook.Expired);
        Console.WriteLine("Don't save: {0}", cook.Discard);
        Console.WriteLine("Comment: {0}", cook.Comment);
        Console.WriteLine("Uri for comments: {0}", cook.CommentUri);
        Console.WriteLine("Version: RFC {0}", cook.Version == 1 ? "2109" : "2965");

        // Show the string representation of the cookie.
        Console.WriteLine("String: {0}", cook.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: this code doesn't read cookies from FireFox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[For security reasons and according to the HTTP-Standard a request/response only contains cookies which the specific domain is allowed to see which usually is just its own cookies!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Privacy_and_third-party_cookies).

You code has nothing to do with Firefox (or any browser for that matter) - it just connects to a domain and prints out the cookies it gets back from the server...